# Creating a data vizualization using Python vertical line

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello everyone I got a question about creating a data visualization using python.
I got this following data like this

```
        index   trk  rbegin  rend      suffix  prefix    id
        0     STWOS  130.30  129.00    NaN      H        1
        1   missing  129.00  128.00    NaN      H        1
        2     STWOS  128.00  125.61    NaN      H        1
        3   missing  125.61  125.00    NaN      H        1
         4      STWS  125.00  121.37    NaN      H        1
        5     STWOS  121.37  114.50    NaN      H        1
        6     DTWOS  114.50  106.84    NaN      H        1
       7     STWOS  106.84  101.50    NaN      H        1
      8      STWS  101.50   98.57    NaN      H        1
     9     STWOS   98.57   92.18    NaN      H        1
     10     STWS   92.18   90.25    NaN      H        1
     11    STWOS   90.25   86.00    NaN      H        1
     12    DTWOS   86.00   81.00    NaN      H        1
    13    STWOS   81.00   78.59    NaN      H        1
     14     STWS   78.59   75.07    NaN      H        1
   15    STWOS   75.07   69.71    NaN      H        1
    16     STWS   69.71   67.78    NaN      H        1
     17    STWOS   67.78   60.60    NaN      H        1
      18     STWS   60.60   58.00    NaN      H       1
     19    STWOS   58.00   55.40    NaN      H        1
      20     STWS   55.40   53.31    NaN      H        1
     21    STWOS   53.31   47.96    NaN      H        1
     22     STWS   47.96   45.00    NaN      H        1
     23    STWOS   45.00   43.05    NaN      H        1
     24     STWS   43.05   40.29    NaN      H        1
```

Basically I am trying to create a graph. It is a bunch of vertical from the rbegin to rend.
If the trk is STWOS it is just a black line from rbegin to rend. If the trck is missing it is a black dashed line. if the trk is dtwos it is two parallel black lines.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30rzh.png)

However I cannot get it too look like that I get this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3oUa.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.axes as ax


df1=pd.read_csv("line3.csv")
egs=df1["line_id"]
egs=df1["line_id"]
#for the column return only unique values
egs2=egs.unique()
b=1
a=df1[df1["line_id"]==b]
a=a.sort_values(by="rbegin",ascending=False)
a1=a.drop(["Unnamed: 0","index"],axis=1)
c=max(a1["rbegin"])
d=max(a1["rend"])
z=max(a1["rbegin"])
z2=min(a1["rend"])
ogig=z-z2
r=max(c,d)
a2=a1.to_numpy()
for i in range(0,len(a2)):
    plt.axis(xmin=1,xmax=3)
    yTick=np.arange(0,r,5)
    plt.title("line:"+str(b))
    #plt.yticks(yTick)
    if a2[i][0]=="STWOS":
        plt.vlines(2,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],linewidth=1,color="black")
    if a2[i][0]=="DTWOS":
            plt.annotate(str(a2[i][2]),(1.85,a2[i][2]),fontsize=5)
            plt.vlines(2,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],linewidth=1,color="black")
            plt.vlines(1.95,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],linewidth=1,color="black")
    if a2[i][0]=="DTWS":
        plt.vlines(2,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],linewidth=1,color="black")
        plt.vlines(2.05,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],linewidth=1/2,color="red")
        plt.axhline(y=a2[i][1],xmin=.51,xmax=.53,linewidth=1/7,color="red")
        plt.axhline(y=a2[i][2],xmin=.51,xmax=.53,linewidth=1/7,color="red")
    if a2[i][0]=="missing":
        plt.annotate(str(a2[i][2]),(1.85,a2[i][2]),fontsize=5)
        plt.vlines(2,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],color="black",linewidth=1,linestyles="dashed")
    if a2[i][0]=="STWS":
        plt.annotate(str(a2[i][2]),(1.85,a2[i][2]),fontsize=5)
        plt.vlines(2.05,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],linewidth=1/2,color="red")
        plt.axhline(y=a2[i][1],xmin=.51,xmax=.53,linewidth=1/7,color="red")
        plt.axhline(y=a2[i][2],xmin=.51,xmax=.53,linewidth=1/7,color="red")
        plt.vlines(2,a2[i][1],a2[i][2],linewidth=1,color="black")
fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure().clear()
plt.close()
plt.cla()
plt.clf()
```

Comment: in python, whitespace is important. In the example you've provided, the whitespace is all out of sorts.

Comment: You can create code fences with three backticks \`\`\` on a separate line before and another after the code.

Comment: Ok I used the ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical lines, horizontal lines, and annotations are made into functions to eliminate redundancy in the code. We have also made the y-axis ticks more detailed. Also, since we are handling the data as a data frame, we have changed to using it as is. Also, if you have multiple ids, you need to add a loop process and add the x-axis position value to the drawing function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.axes as ax

def draw_vline(ax, r, x, l, c, ls='solid'):
    ax.vlines(x, r[1], r[2], lw=l, color=c, ls=ls)

def draw_hline(ax, r, l, c):
    ax.axhline(y=r[1], xmin=0.52, xmax=0.54, lw=l, color=c)
    ax.axhline(y=r[2], xmin=0.52, xmax=0.54, lw=l, color=c)
    
def annot(ax, r):
     ax.annotate(str(r[2]),(0.1,r[2]), fontsize=5)
    
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1,8))
ax.axis(xmin=0, xmax=1)
x1,x2,x3 = 0.5,0.45,0.55
b=1

for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    ax.set_title("line:"+ str(b))
    if row[0]=="STWOS":
        draw_vline(ax, row, x1, 1, 'k')
    if row[0]=="DTWOS":
        annot(ax, row)
        draw_vline(ax, row, x1, 1, 'k')
        draw_vline(ax, row, x2, 1, 'k')
    if row[0]=="DTWS":
        draw_vline(ax, row, x1, 1, 'k')
        draw_vline(ax, row, x3, 1/2, 'r')
        draw_hline(ax, row, 1/4, 'r')
    if row[0]=="missing":
        annot(ax, row)
        draw_vline(ax, row, x1, 1, 'k', ls='dashed')
    if row[0]=="STWS":
        annot(ax, row)
        draw_vline(ax, row, x3, 1/2, 'r')
        draw_hline(ax, row, 1/4, 'r')
        draw_vline(ax, row, x1, 1, 'k')
            
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(40,130)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(40.0,131.0,2.5))
ax.grid(color='0.9', lw=0.5, ls='dashed')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can see that the argument of each drawing function is the respective parameter value. If my answer is helpful to you, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the Voting up/down buttons.